# Why I run the script in the colab using cpu rather than cuda?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, yolo

Why the colab prints false for all the check output even though in the first command.

If I don't run this script, the colab return True for `cuda.is_available()`. What is the reason?

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('parser')
parser.add_argument("--device", type=int, required=True)
parser.add_argument("--ckptdeblurGAN", type=str, default="./deblurGANLib/pretrained_weights/WGAN_GP/checkpoint-epoch300.pth")
parser.add_argument("--video_root", type=str, default="./imgAndVideos/video/")
parser.add_argument("--cfg", type=str, default="cfg/my_yolov3.cfg")
parser.add_argument("--weights",
                    type=str,
                    default="./weights/yolov3spp-59_deblurGAN.pt")
parser.add_argument("--img_size", type=int, default=512)
parser.add_argument(
    "--deep_checkpoint",
    type=str,
    default="deep_sort/deep/checkpoint/resnet50_best_centerloss_final.pt")

# hyperparameter
parser.add_argument("--max_dist", type=float, default=0.2)

# presentation
parser.add_argument("--display", dest="display", action="store_true", default=False)
parser.add_argument("--display_width", type=int, default=1280)
parser.add_argument("--display_height", type=int, default=720)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(torch.cuda.is_available())

if torch.cuda.is_available() and args.device >= 0:
    
    device = torch.device(f'cuda:{args.device}')
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(1234)
else:
    device = torch.device('cpu')
    torch.manual_seed(1234)
    
print("check!",device)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the runtime setting:

Runtime-> Modify the runtime type -> select GPU

Link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/google_colab/google_colab_using_free_gpu.htm

Comment: Hi, Yuser, Thanks for your help, I knew the settings and I am using GPU Tesla P100 now.

Comment: Hi Channing, the colab prints True for both of the print. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ayB4-zUSw7iEXMJLSHQZCIdbsBWRUySj?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, that's good, how can you get the result? Did you paste my codes to a new file and run it in the colab? I always get the false...

Comment: Yes, exactly, I pasted your code to a new file on colab and ran it. Perhaps you could share your colab notebook ?

Comment: I can print the same things if I comment on part of the codes. It seems that the cuda can check imported files if they will use the cuda device or not. I am not clear on that.